# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!-\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}-\ln(n^2+3n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

My professor of Analysis has said that to simplify the factorial I can use Stirling's formula, but I don't know very well what it is or how to apply it.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n!-\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}-\ln(n^2+3n)}$$

I have tried with Stolz but it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no need for Stirling's approximation, such limit is clearly $+\infty$ by elementary inequalities.

Comment: You don't need Stirling's formula (as @MichaelRozenberg pointed out). Anyway, the formula is:$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stirling Formula gives an good approximation of how $n!$  behaves when $n \rightarrow +\infty$, it is given by
$$
n! \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$Indeed you can use it here, but careful, you cannot sum the $\sim$ relation.

However you can use that
$$
\frac{n!-\sin\left(2n\right)}{n!}=1-\frac{\sin\left(2n\right)}{n!} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}1
$$
And
$$
\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)!}-\ln\left(n^2+3n\right)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}=1-\frac{\ln\left(n^2+3n\right)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}1
$$
Hence

> $$
> \frac{n!-\sin\left(2n\right)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}-\ln\left(n^2+3n\right)}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}
> $$

Comment: For example, when I tried $20!$ with the formula is a negative number, why?

Comment: The expression $$ \sqrt{2n \pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$ is positive so it is impossible. Or you have used it directly in the limit you were searching but as i said you cannot " sum " this relation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n!-\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}-\ln(n^2+3n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{n!}{n+1}}-\frac{\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}}{1-\frac{\ln(n^2+3n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}}=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that $\sin$ and $\ln$ are irrelevant in the computation. Thus, the limit dependens only on the ratio between the two factorial expressions, the one at the denominator  being "almost" the square root of the other one. Formalizing:

$\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!-\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}-\ln(n²+3n)}\sim\\ \sim\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{\sqrt{(n+1)}n!^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\\ =\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{n!}{n+1}} \to +\infty\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of limits the key point is to recognize that $n!$ and $\sqrt{(n+1)!}$ are "bigger" than all others terms, thus an efficent way to solve is to collect them

$$\dfrac{n!-\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}-\ln(n^2+3n)}=\frac{n!}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}\dfrac{1-\frac{\sin(2n)}{n!}}{1-\frac{\ln(n^2+3n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}}\to+\infty\cdot\frac{1-0}{1-0}=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$ \dfrac{n!-\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!} - \log(n^2+3n)} \gt$

$\dfrac{n! -1}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}} \gt$

$\dfrac{n!}{\sqrt{(n+1)n!}} -\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}=$

$\sqrt{n!}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)}} -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \gt$

$\sqrt{(n-2)!} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}.$

The limit $n \rightarrow \infty$  is ?

Used: $n(n-1) \gt n+1$, for $n\ge 3.$